# Fourier transform of a sequence by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $H$ the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb Z^n,\mathbb C^n)$.
For $u\in H$, denote by $\mathcal{F}(u)$ the Fourier transform of $u$, defined by $\displaystyle \mathcal{F}(u)(x_1,\ldots, x_n)= \left( \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n}u_{k}^{(1)}e^{-i\langle k, x\rangle},\ldots, \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n}u_{k}^{(n)}e^{-i\langle k, x\rangle} \right)^T$.

> I'd like to express $\mathcal{F}(Au)$, where $A$ is a real symmetric
>   $n\times n$ matrix, as a factor of $\mathcal{F}(u)$.

I did it by hand for $n=2$ and I get $\mathcal{F}(Au) = \begin{pmatrix}b+c & 0 \\ 0 &a+b\end{pmatrix}A \mathcal{F}(u)$, if $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c\end{pmatrix}$. Is there a "simple generic" formula for every dimension?